# Javascript inserting data into cell with index and data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, cells

This seems very simple but I just can't get my head around it. I am trying to insert data I get back and replace the cell contents at the specified cell index. I am getting the data (`Kevin`) and index (`0`) back from the function call's input parameters. But I'm just not able to insert this data into the desired cell. I have tried `insertCell` function, but this won't replace the contents, it'll just keep appending new cells.

My console.logs report the correct index and data, I've tried inserting/replacing the content of the cell like this: `td[index].innerHTML = data` but this gives an error, apparently `td[index]` returns a `object HTMLTableCellElement`, so i can't do it this way.

HTML:

```
      <table>
            ...
            <tbody>
                <tr id="data-row-body">
                    <td></td> //need to insert here
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Javscript:

```
function exeAPI(api, key, index, callback) {
$.ajax({
      url:"../lib/getData.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
          name: name,
          api: api
      },
      dataType: "text", 
      success:function(result){
          console.log(result);
        if(result){
            try {
                var jsonText = result.substr(result.indexOf('{'));
                console.log("this is the jsontext: " + jsonText);  
                var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonText);

                callback(jsonObj.response.result[key], index);
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e);
                alert("Error getting rack data!");
            }
        }
      }
});

//getting back "Kevin" and "0" as parameters to insert here

function exeAPIcallback(data, index){
    var td = $('#data-table tbody td');
    var tr = $('#data-table tbody tr');
    var row = document.getElementById("data-row-body");
    console.log("This is the cell index: " + th[index].innerHTML + " ,index: " + th[index]);
    console.log("This is the cell index: " + td[index]);

    td[index].innerHTML = data; // this doesn't work

}



function popupParamChecker(){

exeAPI("getData.php", "Kevin", 0, exeAPIcallback);

$("#dialog-params").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    width: 1000,
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    buttons: {
        Confirm: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});
}
```

Is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: the is the `data` i get back, which is `Kevin`.

Comment: I did already, it isnt a empty string. When i do this     `var tr = $('<tr>'); $('<td>').html(data).appendTo(tr); tbody.append(tr)` i see the correct value in the first index. It works when i do it this way using append, and removing the `<td>` and `<tr>` from the html. But i need a way to use my desired index values, and also i can't keep appending, it needs to replace the currently cell index.

Comment: `$('<td>').html(data)` is very dangerous, it may destroy something.

Comment: @Sphinx yes, but why does it work with `append`, and not with your suggested solution? Is the data not ready when dialog is created?

Comment: @Sphinx do you have a solution using `append`? When i click the button two times or more i just keep seeing the data `Kevin` being appending into the table, i need a way to give it the desired index and replace the data.

Comment: In my solution, my selector is `$('table tbody tr')`, probably you need to try `$('#data-table tbody tr')` in your project.

Comment: @Sphinx i did that `$('#data-table tbody tr')` but still nothing in my table :(

Comment: try this way: added `class="target-td"` into `$('#data-table tbody td')`, then modify exeAPICallback to `function exeAPIcallback(data, row, col){console.log('tell me what is the value:', $('.target-td').html());$('.target-td').eq(0).text('test');}`;

Comment: So, i called it like this `$('#flight-data-table tbody tr').eq(0).find('td').eq(index).text(result);` and it actually did update the first cell to Kevin (i only have 1 row so i set row to 0). But when i call the function twice like this:  `exeAPI("GetStatus.php", "name", 0, exeAPIcallback); //Kevin
    exeCtCoreAPI("GetStatus.php", "number", 1, exeAPIcallback); //xxx-xxx-xxxx` It doesn't insert the second cell into the position of index 1.

Comment: @Sphinx Nevermind, it is working now, the second result was `null` that is why it didnt update... Thanks for your help!! :)

Comment: @Sphinx Actually, one last question for you. Do you think calling the function 5 times is unnecessary? could i use prototypes to do this to save memory?

Comment: Why you need to call this function 5 times?

Comment: @Sphinx Because I have different php scripts that return different JSON data, and i dont want to create a seprate function for each php script. so i just created the functions above to be able to quickly insert the php script and the key as parameters i am interested in. And the reason I need to call it five times, is I need the name, phone, address, gender, work(from another php script), ...etc.

Comment: @Sphinx so i can call it like this `exeAPI("getData.php", "name", 0, exeAPIcallback); exeAPI("getData.php", "number", 1, exeAPIcallback); exeAPI("getWork.php", "work", 3, exeAPIcallback);` ...etc

Comment: it would be fine for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count of row may be many, so I added one param for your APICallback.

Below is the codes:

**1.** First select our all rows under the table by `$('table tbody tr')`

**2.** use [`.eq(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the specific row

**3.** [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) all tds then get the specific cell to change the text.

```js
function exeAPIcallback1(data, row, col){
  let td = $('table tbody tr').eq(row).find('td').eq(col);
  td.text(td.text()+data)
}

function exeAPIcallback2(data, row, col){
  $('table tbody tr').eq(row).find('td').eq(col).text(data);
}
```

```css
table td{
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  border:1px;
  background-color:yellow;
}

table td:nth-child(even){
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="exeAPIcallback1('test',0,0)"> Test Insert</button>
<button onclick="exeAPIcallback2('test',0,0)"> Test Replace</button>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="data-row-body">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for that, but that didn't work :( So my td tags are within a dialog box triggered by button click event. I think instead of replacing the text within the defined td I have to use insertCell to create a new td instead.

Comment: Ahh tried your revised solution and still no luck, I'm thinking by the time the dialog is triggered the text doesn't get updated in time.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following **function** to add content to a table cell.

```
function add_content_to_cell(table_selector, row_number, cell_number, content) {
    $(table_selector).find('tr')
    .eq(row_number-1).find('td').eq(cell_number-1)
    .append(content); 
    }
```

Simply choose the table id, the row number, the cell number and the content you wish to add.

**Usage**:

```
add_content_to_cell('#my_table', 2, 5, "I am some content")
```

**Result**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
$('#data-row-body').find('td').eq(index).text(data); /* strips down html, if any */
```

OR

```
$('#data-row-body').find('td').eq(index).html(data); /* with html tags */
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `$('#data-row-body').find('td').eq(index).text(data)`

Comment: Thank you for that, but that didn't work :( So my `td` tags are within a dialog box triggered by button click event. I think instead of replacing the text within the defined `td` I have to use insertCell to create a new `td` instead.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works, with your current snippet

change

```
var td = $('#data-table tbody td');
```

to

```
var td = $('#data-row-body').children('td');
```

```
$(td[index]).html(data);
```

here, assuming that index is always within the bounds of